# Django model not saving when calling save()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-socialauth, tastypie

so i am trying to save a django model, and for some reason i am only getting a 500 internal server error. the thing is,

> if i comment the social_auth.save() it works and i can manipulate the
>   object, but not save it

why is this happening? i am using django tastypie and i am trying to save a django-social-auth instance.

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        #this is not supposed to upgrade password
        bundle = super(UserResource, self).obj_create(bundle)
        bundle.obj.save()
        if bundle.data.get('extra_data') != None:
            print bundle.data.get('extra_data')
            fb_id = bundle.data.get('extra_data')['id']
            #social_auth=UserSocialAuth(user_id = bundle.obj, provider=bundle.data.get('provider'),uid=fb_id,extra_data=bundle.data.get('extra_data') )
            social_auth=UserSocialAuth()
            social_auth.user_id = bundle.obj
            social_auth.provider=bundle.data.get('provider')
            social_auth.uid=fb_id
            social_auth.extra_data=bundle.data.get('extra_data')


            print "social: ",social_auth.extra_data
            social_auth.save()

    except IntegrityError:
        raise BadRequest('Username already exists')

    return bundle
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp_3.py", line 23, in <module>
    post()
  File "temp_3.py", line 18, in post
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

Comment: what does the stack trace say ?

Comment: nothing much, but i just added the traceback above

Comment: if bundle.obj is of type `User`, then `social_auth.user_id = bundle.obj` is wrong and should be `social_auth.user = bundle.obj`

Comment: that's it now works... you can write an answer and i will mark it as correct.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if bundle.obj is of type `User`, then `social_auth.user_id = bundle.obj` is wrong and should be `social_auth.user = bundle.obj`

also ensure you are not in this case:

[django-social-auth HTTP 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463320/how-can-i-handle-exceptions-raised-by-django-social-auth)